# mongoimport: how to monitor execution time?

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, mongoimport

I'm running MongoDB on Ubuntu 14.04.

I'm successfully importing data from CSV into MongoDB, but I want to be able to get a reading of the total execution time for the operation.

I've been using the .explain() command to monitor query CRUD operations executed within mongodb.exe itself, but this obviously won't work on the import process which is executed from the bin level.

Please can anyone advise how I can easily get a performance reading for the import? (i've had a cast around and can't find any suitable guidance).

The code I'm using for the import is:

```
 jon@ubuntu:~/Desktop/mongodb-linux-x86_64-2.6.3/bin$ mongoimport --db jontestcsv --collection Aircraft --ignoreBlanks --type csv --headerline --file /home/jon/Desktop/Aircraft.csv
```

Greatly appreciate any guidance.

Regards,
Jon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Use the `time` utility

If you're just after the execution time of the script, you can prefix your `mongoimport` command line with the standard Unix-ish utility [`time`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/time.1.html), eg:

```
time mongoimport --db jontestcsv --collection Aircraft --ignoreBlanks --type csv --headerline --file /home/jon/Desktop/Aircraft.csv
```

> time runs the program COMMAND with any given arguments ARG. When
>          COMMAND finishes, time displays information about resources used by
>          COMMAND (on the standard error output, by default).  If COMMAND exits
>          with non-zero status, time displays a warning message and the exit
>          status.

#### Grep the `mongod` logs

With a bit more effort you could also grep the information from the `mongod` log, if you identify the connection ID for the `mongoimport` job. For example, in the log snippet below you could calculate the time difference between connection #27 from localhost being accepted and ending by grepping for `127.0.0.1:64023`:

```
2014-07-21T06:20:59.143+1000 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:64023 #27 (2 connections now open)
2014-07-21T06:20:59.180+1000 [conn27] build index on: test.twitter properties: { v: 1, key: { _id: 1 }, name: "_id_", ns: "test.twitter" }
2014-07-21T06:20:59.182+1000 [conn27]    added index to empty collection
2014-07-21T06:21:05.705+1000 [FileAllocator] allocating new datafile /data/test.1, filling with zeroes...
2014-07-21T06:21:05.709+1000 [FileAllocator] creating directory /data/_tmp
2014-07-21T06:21:06.337+1000 [FileAllocator] done allocating datafile data/test.1, size: 128MB,  took 0.618 secs
2014-07-21T06:21:06.343+1000 [conn27] insert test.twitter ninserted:1 keyUpdates:0 numYields:0 locks(micros) w:663227 663ms
2014-07-21T06:21:11.924+1000 [conn27] end connection 127.0.0.1:64023 (1 connection now open)
```

Comment: Many thanks, that works great. It returns: Sun Jul 20 13:44:04.758 imported 4651 objects

real 0m1.567s
user 0m0.409s
sys 0m0.299s
So I'll take 'real' as the total execution time. Many thanks for your help. Jon